# error after migration from swift 1.2 to swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in

            self.layoutIfNeeded()

            }) { (finished) -> Void in
    .......
    .......
    }
```

this code throws this error: 
Cannot convert value of type '(_) throws -> Void' to expected argument type '((Bool) -> Void)?'

Comment: Please formulate a question.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you are not closing correctly the parentheses and missing the completion argument.
The most easy way to detect this kind of errors is try to rewrite the method.
Try this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            ///
    })
```

Comment: This code doesn't display ani error and complies fine, thus it can be something that you call inside

Answer (score 0):

Write like below code, this will work bcz its working at my side,

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in

        //your code here
        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        }) { (flag : Bool) -> Void in

            ///
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that generates the same xcode, try this.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { 
    // Code for animation

}) { (finished: Bool) in
    // Code for completion
}
```